# sunspot not indexing objects created in rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

Sunspot doesn't seem to be indexing objects created using rake tasks. I can't find anything in the docs about that one way one or another. Is this normal? I'm using sunspot_rails 1.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is fully normal. If you want Solr to index changes made from rake task, use Sunspot's commands Sunspot.index and Sunspot.commit after creating activerecord objects.

http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/classes/Sunspot.html

Comment: Is there a particular reason for this? My assumption was that indexes would be updated every time a save() callback was issued. How are rake tasks different that this behaviour doesn't occur?

Comment: Updated link for above: http://sunspot.github.com/docs/Sunspot.html#commit-class_method